# How to insert a documentation comment in sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text, I know that `Ctrl + /` comments the current line, and `Ctrl + Shift + /` inserts a multi-line comment at the cursor.

How to insert a documentation comment of the form

```
/**
 * documentation comment
 */
```

To do this manually, type `/**` and press `Enter`, later close the comment with a `/`.
How can I do this using a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a snippet via a key binding (Preferences / Key Bindings):

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+4"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "/**\n * $SELECTION\n */"} }
]
```

Save the settings, and then press Ctrl-Shift-4. If you have a line highlighted,
it should be inserted in the right place. But if you have multiple lines selected, it won't properly add asterisks in front of each line.

Answer (score 0):

As Scovetta noted in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245999/1426065), the snippet they presented only works for single-line comments, and I don't think I've ever encountered a single-line documentation comment, as that's just not their intended use.

Instead, I'd highly recommend using the [`DocBlockr`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DocBlockr) plugin. All you need to do is type `/**` on an empty line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it automatically begins each line with  `*`. It also automatically puts  `*/` at the end.

[image: Doc block completion]

`DocBlockr` also works with regular comments - just type `/*` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it automatically inserts a blank new line followed by `*/`.

If you start a doc block on the line just before a function definition, `DocBlockr` will automatically fill in the parameters:

[image: Automatic function documentation]

There are lots of other features too: automatic processing of type hints, `//` comment reformatting, variable documentation, and more. It's a really useful plugin for C/C++, Java, JavaScript, and other similar languages.

Note: I'm not affiliated with the plugin or its authors in any way.